# Can I sort mySQL database records by the sum of multiple columns without displaying the sum itself?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, sum

I have a database of football players and their stats where the first three fields are VARCHAR and the rest are INT. I want to display the records in DESC order based on the total sum of their stats BUT I don't want to display the total sum.

Here is some example data entered into the database:

```
Tim Tebow          NYJ         QB          315             2             62             1
Tom Brady          NE          QB          344             3             13             0
Tony Romo          DAL         QB          337             4             25             0
```

and how I'd like it to display (in order of the sum of PASS_YDS + PASS_TDS + RUSH_YDS + RUSH_TDS):

```
Player        |   Team    |   Pos   |   PASS_YDS   |   PASS_TDS   |   RUSH_YDS   |   RUSH_TDS
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tim Tebow          NYJ         QB          315             2             62             1
Tony Romo          DAL         QB          337             4             25             0
Tom Brady          NE          QB          344             3             13             0
```

Here is the query I am using to fetch the data from my database and display it in a table on a page, sorted by PASS_YDS in descending order (yes, I know mysql_ is deprecated - I will be revamping the app very soon but just need to get it working right this way first):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Player, Team, Pass_Yds, Pass_TDs, Int_Thrown, Rush_Yds, Rush_TDs, Total_Fantasy_Pts FROM ff_projections WHERE Position = 'QB' ORDER BY Pass_Yds DESC;");
```

What do I need to do in order to sort it the way I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly as one might imagine:

```sql
SELECT   Player, Team, Pass_Yds, Pass_TDs, Int_Thrown, Rush_Yds, Rush_TDs
FROM     ff_projections
WHERE    Position = 'QB'
ORDER BY Pass_Yds + Pass_TDs + Rush_Yds + Rush_TDs DESC
```

However, just because one includes a column in the select list doesn't mean that your application has to use that column...

Comment: LOL - that was my first instinct, but I'm so new to this, I thought that it couldn't possibly be that logical so I started Googling and reading posts here and got myself all turned around. :) Thank you!

Comment: And you don't need to select a column because you use it in the WHERE or ORDER BY clause...

Comment: Do you that I can omit Pass_Yds, Pass_TDs, Rush_Yds, and Rush_TDs from my SELECT list because they already appear in my ORDER BY list?

Comment: You can omit them from the select because YOU don't want them... How cool is that? Don't want to be rude but I really think you should read up on SQL before asking these basic questions.

Comment: I wasn't including them all because I thought I needed them. I included them all because they all need to be in the table. As far as reading up on SQL - I am reading up on it. I sort of got this dropped in my lap and there was nobody else who could do it so I'm having to learn by doing. If my questions are too basic, I apologize but if I don't ask, I won't learn.